# Do I need to encrypt the streams too when using java ssl socket?

Tags: java, sockets, encryption, ssl

I'm currently working on a client/server based Java-program for a customer. 
I googled a bit and got results saying to use sockets and also got some threads about SSL sockets.

Do I have to encrypt the streams too with SSL Sockets or is the connection with SSL Sockets pretty safe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSL sockets will already be encrypted. No need to encrypt the streams manually.